# jQuery 4 hacer split() por espacios pero no hacer split si se ponen muchos espacios sin nada escrito

Tags: html, jquery

Buenas tengo este `input`:

```
<input id="etiquetas"  type="text" class="form-control" name="etiquetas" >
```

Y quiero **separar por espacios** las palabras introducidas, pero encuentro un problema: si escribo por ejemplo `palabra1` `palabra2` `palabra3` `palabra4` `palabra5` `espacio` `espacio` `espacio`

Eso me devuelve un `array` de **8 elementos** pues me cuenta los **espacios** que he puesto sin contener nada, **¿Como puedo hacerlo para que salte los espacios en blanco ?**

Este es mi codigo `jQuery`:

```
  //dividir las etiquetas con 'split()'
            $('#etiquetas').on('change',function(event) {
                var dato = $('#etiquetas').val();
                var array = new Array();
                array = dato.split(' ');

                console.log(array);

            });
```

Comment: te sugiero usar "trim"... var dato = $.trim( $('#etiquetas').val());....

Comment: con esto eliminas los espacios del inicio y del final, mayor referencia: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
 //dividir las etiquetas con 'split()'
$('#etiquetas').on('change',function(event) {
    var dato = $('#etiquetas').val();
    // remplazamos los espacios continuos con 1 solo y eliminamos los espacios al inicio y final!
    dato = dato.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    var array = new Array();
    array = $.trim(dato).split(' ');

    console.log(array);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="etiquetas"  type="text" class="form-control" name="etiquetas" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando `replace` de javascript y expresiones regulares podemos remplazar y quitar los espacios del inicio y final.

```
//dividir las etiquetas con 'split()'
$('#etiquetas').on('change',function(event) {
    var dato = $('#etiquetas').val();
    // Usando replace y expresiones regulares
    dato = dato.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();
    var array = new Array();
    array = $.trim(dato).split(' ');

    console.log(array);

});
```

Comment: sin el `trim` optenias `["","palabra1", ""]` agregando espacios atras y adelante del teexto